# Uploading files in subdirectories in media directory in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I am using Django 3. I am trying to upload files to specific directories. location='media/dentist/diplomas/' and location='media/dentist/government_docs/' directories. But still files are directly uploaded to /media directory. But i want files to be uploaded into dentist directory under media directory.

```
def create_account_dentist(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    #Upload Dentist Diploma and Government Document
    uploaded_file_url = ""
    uploaded_file_url2 = ""
    if request.FILES['customFileInput1']:
        myfile = request.FILES['customFileInput1']
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location='media/dentist/diplomas/')
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
    if request.FILES['customFileInput2']:
        myfile2 = request.FILES['customFileInput2']        
        fs2 = FileSystemStorage(location='media/dentist/government_docs/')        
        filename2 = fs2.save(myfile2.name, myfile2)        
        uploaded_file_url2 = fs.url(filename2)
        print(uploaded_file_url2)
    return redirect(reverse('dentist-section')) #Forward to Dentist Main Page
return render(request, 'create-account-dentist.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work, but you can also try this instead:

```py
def create_account_dentist(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    #Upload Dentist Diploma and Government Document
    uploaded_file_url = ""
    uploaded_file_url2 = ""
    if request.FILES['customFileInput1']:
        myfile = request.FILES['customFileInput1']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(f'dentist/diplomas/{myfile.name}', myfile) # <--
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
    if request.FILES['customFileInput2']:
        myfile2 = request.FILES['customFileInput2']        
        fs2 = FileSystemStorage()        
        filename2 = fs2.save(f'dentist/government_docs/{myfile2.name}', myfile2) # <--
        uploaded_file_url2 = fs.url(filename2)
        print(uploaded_file_url2)
    return redirect(reverse('dentist-section')) #Forward to Dentist Main Page
return render(request, 'create-account-dentist.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

I changend below code;

```
    fs = FileSystemStorage(location='media/dentist/diplomas/')
    filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
```

as;

```
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    filename = fs.save('dentist/diplomas/' + myfile.name, myfile)
```

and my problem solved.